# Can't define class functions OUTSIDE class

Tags: c++, class, layout, multiple-definition-error

I want to separate Game class into header and source. To do that I need to be able to define the functions outside the class, but, strangely, I can't!

*main.cpp*

```
#include "app.hpp"
int main ()
{
    Game game(640, 480, "Snake");
    game.run();
    return 0;
}
```

*app.hpp*

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
class App
{
    friend class Game;
    public:
             App(const int X, const int Y, const char* NAME);
        void run(void);
    private: // Variables
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        sf::Event         event;
        sf::Keyboard     kboard;
};
#include "game.hpp"
```

**And now the question part.**

*game.hpp*.

```
class Game // this snippet works perfectly
{
    public:
             Game(const int X, const int Y, const char* TITLE) : app(X, Y, TITLE)
             { /* and the initialization of the Game class itself... */}
        void run()
             { app.run(); /* And the running process of Game class itself*/};
    private:
        App app;
};
```

```
class Game // this snippet produces compiler errors of multiple definitions...
{
    public:
             Game(const int X, const int Y, const char* TITLE);
        void run();
    private:
        App app;
};
Game::Game(const int X, const int Y, const char* TITLE) : app(X, Y, TITLE) {}
void Game::run() { app.run(); } // <<< Multiple definitions ^^^
```

**Why?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **What is the reasoning for the multiple definitions error?**

Because you are defining the functions in the header file and when you include the header in translation units a copy of the function is created in each **[translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**, thus leading to multiple definitions and violation of **[one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.

> **What is the solution?**

You can define the functions separately but in a cpp file. You declare functions in header file and define them in source cpp file.

> **Why first example works?**

The only standard compliant way to bypass one definition rule is to use `inline` functions. When you define the functions inside the class body, they are implicitly `inline` and the program can successfully bypass one definition rule and the multiple definition linking error.

Comment: +1. And the first version works because the definitions are implicitly inline.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're defining `class Game` twice.
Here's how you lay out the separation:

Class.hpp

```
class Class
{
    public:
        Class();
        void foo();
};
```

Class.cpp

```
Class::Class() { //Do some stuff}
void Class::foo() { //Do other stuff }
```